# Especificar method para el action (url pasarela bancaria) en un modulo Payment

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop1.7

Estoy desarrollando un módulo en prestashop para implementar una pasarela de pago y me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.

Haciendo uso de lo que indica en la documentación para desarrollar módulos de tipo payment (https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/payment/#payment-modules) he implementado el método **getExternalPaymentOption** que permite configurar una pasarela con url externa (url de la pasarela bancaria).

```
public function getExternalPaymentOption()
{
    $externalOption = new \PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption();
    $externalOption->setCallToActionText($this->l('Pay external'))
                   ->setAction("<<URL_PASARELA BANCARIA>>")
                   ->setAdditionalInformation($this->context->smarty->fetch('module:paymentexample/views/templates/front/payment_infos.tpl'))
                   ->setLogo(Media::getMediaPath(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$this->name.'/payment.jpg'));

    return $externalOption;
}
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema es que la url de la pasarela bancaria que estoy usando, exige que el method sea **GET** y por defecto prestashop realiza un **POST** por los que la llamada me devuelve error.

Por más que miro la clase PaymentOptions.php, no veo manera de indicar el method por ninguna parte y eso que en un comentario indica esto:

```php
    /**
     * An associative array of additional parameters to use when sending
     * the request to $action,
     * e.g. if  $action is "http://payment-provider.example.com/process",
     *          $method is "GET"
     *      and $inputs is ['customerName' => 'bob']
     *      then the request will be made to:
     *          "http://payment-provider.example.com/process?customerName=bob".
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $inputs;
    ...
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto? estoy algo atascado

Uso Prestashop v1.7.8.7

Comment: y si usas un proxy file en donde lo que recibes por POST lo recojes y lo envias por GET??? GET=POST;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el método **setAction** no tenés que usar la **URL** de la pasarela bancaria, ahí va la **URL** del controlador de validación:

```php
->setAction($this->context->link->getModuleLink($this->name, 'validation', array(), true));
```

Es donde el pago se va a procesar y desde ahí podés realizar el request **GET** a tu **API externa**.

La ruta del controlador es:
`modules/<nombreDeTuModulo>/controllers/front/validation.php`

En el punto 5 del siguiente tutorial, hay un ejemplo concreto de un controlador de validación:
https://andresa.dev/en/prestashop-1-7-how-to-create-a-new-payment-module-part-1/

Comment: Perfecto, ya he conseguido avanzar con este tip. Desde la validación se tiene todo el control de pago, ya sea para redirigir, mostrar algún error etc. Muchas gracias!